# Apply function to every column in every table in list R

Tags: r

I have a list of tables in R. The number of rows differs from table to table but the number of columns is uniform (22). I need to calculate the min,max,and median of each column in each table and put that into a vector. There needs to be a separate vector per table.

Comment: -1 Although I did answer your question you are required (to post on this site) to show that you did some research and to post a reproducible example we can work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lapply(your_list,function(x){apply(x,2,mean)})
```

Replace `mean` by `min`, `max` or `median`  according to which one you want to calculate.

`apply(x,2,...)` apply the function on each column (i. e. 2nd dimension) of matrix, array or dataframe.
`lapply(...)` apply the function to each element of a list.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sorry about not including any examples, this is my first time using the site. Thanks for going easy on me.